# Get Websites Title

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, attributes, title

I am trying to retrieve the title of a URL for a link.

For example get the title of this:

`<a class="stack" href="http://stackoverflow.com" title="Stack Overflow">`

will be generated dynamically from something like this: `$('.stack').attr("title", "....");`.

Is that possible with javascript or jQuery to retrieve the title of a URL?

Thanks alot

Comment: So do you want to get the title of a url you choose, or the title attribute of that element?

Comment: @ItayMoav I know sorry trying to improve.

Comment: @drake I am trying to retrieve the title of the href.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a little time to make, but this example allows you download a web page from your web page. Then extract the title from the title tags.

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- jQuery include -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- This include allows cross domain get requests -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/jamespadolsey/jQuery-Plugins/master/cross-domain-ajax/jquery.xdomainajax.js"></script>

<!-- Sample -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    //gets the href of the first anchor
    var url = $("a").first().attr("href");

    //sets a get request to get the html source
    $.get(url, function(data){
        //uses get string between function to get the text between the title tags
        //then calls it in a message box
        alert(getStringBetween(data.responseText, "<title>", "</title>"));
    }); 
});

function getStringBetween(input, start, end){
    var index = input.indexOf(start);

    if(index != -1){
        index += start.length;
        var endIndex = input.indexOf(end, index + 1);

        if(endIndex != -1)
            return input.substr(index, endIndex - index);
    }
    return false;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This will only work within your domain.  Also, you should parse the HTML using jQuery instead of doing string matching.  (What about `<tiTle>`?)

Comment: @SLaks how about you attempt the code I just gave before claiming it doesn't work.

Comment: You are using a server-side proxy; I hadn't noticed that.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, just use `document.title`. Simple and effective.

```
$('.stack').attr("title", document.title);
```

EDIT: It looks like I misunderstood your question. If you want to get the title of another page, not the currently loaded page, you could do some cross-domain AJAX trickery, but it's not generally a good idea. I'd just grab the page title server side (in whatever you are using to generate the page [php, asp, etc]) and output it.

Comment: This sets the link's title to current page's title (`document.title`). Don't think that's what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, you cannot read content from a different website using Javascript, even just to read the title.

You could write a server-side proxy that requests a remote page and finds its `<title>` tag using an HTML parser.

However, you shouldn't do this at the client side; it will waste time and resources.
If you really want to do this, do it once on the server as a pre-processing step when you create a new page.

Comment: Right okay now I get this. Basically I am looking for something like the famous bookmark sites use. For example http://delicious.com/ gives you the title of that page... Does that makes sense?

Comment: They do it in advance on the server.

Comment: On your edit: It's a little bookmark site. I can't think of another way to do this. I mean the client adds a website, you need to give him a title...

Comment: You mean using server-side proxy?

Comment: Yes.  If you need to show the title as the user adds before reloading, you'll need to use AJAX with a proxy.  Otherwise, you should look up the title when you add a bookmark and store it in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the URL's href is on the domain of the current document, using JavaScript to try to get the title of the target document would require cross-domain scripting which is not generally allowed (using traditional methods) by browsers. Unless you're real fancy with proxies (not entirely sure how that is done), you'll need a server-side language to load the document first.

Comment: Or, basically, what SLaks said! Sorry, didn't see your answer!

Comment: Server sided scripting is not needed when you use the correct plugin

Comment: @Drake: Wrong.  Unless the page is within your side (and he implies that it isn't), you need server-side code.